# Adding an Edit Text to Android SnackBar

Tags: java, android

I have created an an activity in android studio and have added a snack-bar. I would like to add an Edit-text to the snack-bar as i would like to use it as a filtering feature. Is that possible?

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinator), "Filter By Location", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Snackbar Action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Snackbars` are shown for a short period of time. They can have links to undo some destructive actions but they should never have `EditText` or other views.

Comment: i do agree with @Gonzalo

Comment: if you want something like snackbar but with edittext then create custom view and add animations for show and hide